# Making multiple requests with Alamofire depending on array of chunks

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm struggling with making badge requests with `Alamofire` and I need help.

I have some ids and with them I need to struct parameters (Dictionary String) and send a **GET** request with `Alamofire`. Everything is fine, but I need to cover the case when ids are above **200**, because when they are more than **200**, API returns **414** code status (too long URL). So when ids are more than 200 they are separated in **chunks**. With each chunk I'm making a new request to API. The problem is that I return only the first 200 ids when I call my method. Here is an example:

```
func request (_ idsDict: [String: [String]], _ idSchema: String, _ completion: @escaping Result<SomeModel, Error>) -> Void {
        let chunks = transformEntitiesIdsToChunks(idsDict)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        chunks.forEach {chunk in
            let parameters = constructQueryParams(idsDict, chunk, idSchema, apiKey, clientId)
            AF.request(baseURL, parameters: parameters).response { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    // some error handling for decoding and no data

                    completion(.success(data.data))
                case .failure(let error):
                    return completion(.failure(error.localizedDescription))
                }
            }
        }
    }

// Method wraps AF request in a continuation block and makes sure that the closure from request method returned data or throwed error.

// That way fetching from API becomes async/await and can be used in do/try/catch block.

func getIdsEntities (_ idsDict: [String: [String]], _ idSchema: String) async throws -> [SomeModel] {
        return try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            request(idsDict, idSchema) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let data):
                    continuation.resume(returning: data)
                    return
                case .failure(let error):
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried with **recursive functions** and with `DispatchGroup` but none of them worked. Any help will be appriciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The issue is that you call `completion(.success(data.data))` on each chunck. You want instead of keep an array of data and append them: `let chunkResponses: [SomeModel]`, and instead of `completion(.success(data.data))`, do chunkResponses.append(contentsOf: data)`, and once all the chunks have been processed, call `completion()`.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for reaching out. Gladly that did help and I'm grateful for your advice. I did it with `DispatchGroup` and your approach. Thanks again. Just another quick question: When I retrieve this data and save it to Core Data and try to fetch it from there when I have enabled `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` my app crashes. The second time I execute the app and then everything is fine. Also when `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` is disabled my app doesn't crash at all. Do I need enabled this flag? My App crashes with this `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x185874d3c)`

Comment: That's another question, and it's about CoreData... Read more about it that flag. it's for debug purpose, and point you to a potential issue that might currently work, but it's "safe" (thread/queue safe), and might causes issues later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `Larme's` comment I was able to find my mistake. When making request to API I was passing the decoded response to the **completion closure**. To fix this I had to declare an array of model `let responses:[SomeModel] = []` and append the decoded result to it. I used `let group = DispatchGroup()` so I can wait the requests to execute and have my final array of results and then I used `group.notify(queue: .main, execute: {completion(.success(responses))})` to return to the main queue and have my array of completed fetched data. This is now how my code looks like:

```
 private func request (_ idsDict: [String: [String]], _ idSchema: String, _ completion: @escaping APIListResponseClosure<SomeModel>) -> Void {
        var responses: [SomeModel] = []
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        let chunks = transformEntitiesIdsToChunks(idsDict)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        chunks.forEach {chunk in
            group.enter()
            let parameters = constructQueryParams(idsDict, chunk, idSchema, apiKey, clientId)
            AF.request(baseURL, parameters: parameters).response { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    // some error handling for decoding and no data

                    responses.append(data.data)
                    group.leave()
                case .failure(let error):
                    return completion(.failure(.APIError(error.localizedDescription)))
                }
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main, execute:  {
            print("Ids are fetched")
            completion(.success(responses))
        })
    }
```

Thanks again to `Larme` and I hope I helped someone else with this case.